# Find the path in a graph, that requires the least amount of nodes to visit

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the shortest way in a non-circular graph. However, the shortest path is not defined as the one with the least weight, but the one with the least number of nodes to visit before reaching the destination.

Let me give you an example: Let's assume you use bad timer app on your phone, which timer is limited to half an hour. There are three buttons:

- add 10 minutes
- add 1 minute
- subtract one minute

The initial value is zero. The input range is 0 to 30 minutes. We now want to set a timer for let's say 29 min. The shortest path to accomplish this is by hitting `add 10 min` three times and `subtract 1 min` one time.

We represent every permutation of button presses in a graph (where every node represents a click on one of the three buttons). We are now looking for a way from start to a specific number, that has the least amount of button presses on it.

Comment: If every edge has a wight of `1`, wouldn't the shortest path be the permutation with the least possible button presses?

Comment: @zois - exactly. I´m looking for an algorithm to count the number of button presses on every possible path, that results in the given time and return the one with the least amount of nodes.

Comment: Have you tried Djikstra's algorithm? Maybe I am not understanding well the issue.

If you represent every button of every permutation with a node, I think shortest path algorithms should return the shortest path you are looking for.

Comment: To confirm: Each node of the graph represents a button. The graph is complete, including from each node to itself. The goal is to find the shortest path such that the sum of node values equals some target. If this is right,

Comment: @zois I think you‘re right - Dijkstra should do the job. Since it adds up the efforts to get from one vertex to another, the shortest path should also be the one with the least nodes (if every edge has a weight of 1). Thank you!

Comment: Your claim about the `non-circular graph` is wrong. I am going to explain it in my answer (of this problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved using `breadth first search` (BFS). Problem is given a starting time (which we consider as starting node of the graph) and a target time (which we consider as destination node). In every step, we can do either of the following with the current time:

1. Add 10 minutes
2. Add 1 minute
3. Subtract 1 minute

Now, the nodes of the graph will be the time we can reach using either of the above steps. For example, starting from time 0 (consider it as node-id 0) we can reach to wither `10`, `1`, or `-1` (i.e., nodes) in one step. So, in one step we discover three different nodes of the graph and non of them is our destination node.

With this three newly discovered nodes, we can do the similar moves and reach to some new nodes which are 2-step away from the source node (i.e., time 0). Here is the list of nodes we can discover in our second step:

- From `10` to: `20`, `11`, `9`
- From `1` to: `11`, `2`, `0`
- From `-1` to: `9`, `0`, `-2`

There are couple of thing we can notice from here:

1. If we discover a node which we never discovered before, then the steps it required to discover is the shortest distance. For example, we can reach to node `9` by 2 steps from the source node `0` (here we can see, `9` can be reached from both nodes `10` and `-1`), and clearly it is the shortest distance for node `9`.
2. The graph can be circular. For example, there is an edge from node `0` to node `-1`, and from node `-1` to node `0`. You need to handle that.

So, it is clear now that we transform this problem to a standard BFS problem. Now, we can solve it by the following pseudo code:

```
Shortest-Path(initial-time, target-time):
    Queue<time> Q
    Map<time, step> M     // this map will help tracking whether we discover a node before or not
    
    Q.insert(initial-time)
    M[initial-time] = 0
    while(!Q.empty):
        current-time = Q.front()
        Q.pop()

        if current-time is equal to target-time:
            return M[current-time]

        if (current-time + 10) is not in the M:
            Q.push(current-time + 10)
            M[(current-time + 10)] = M[current-time] + 1

        if (current-time + 1) is not in the M:
            Q.push(current-time + 1)
            M[(current-time + 1)] = M[current-time] + 1

        if (current-time - 1) is not in the M:
            Q.push(current-time - 1)
            M[(current-time - 1)] = M[current-time] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of the problem as a graph traversal problem, you can solve it simply by performing BFS on a tree that starts with a single root node and grows over time:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
DESIRED_SUM = 29
SET = [-1, 1, 10]
QUEUE = [(0, [])] # For BFS
ANSWER = {} # For Dynamic Programming

while True:
    (cur_sum, elements) = QUEUE.pop(0)

    if cur_sum not in ANSWER:
        ANSWER[cur_sum] = elements

    if cur_sum == DESIRED_SUM:
        break

    for num in SET:
        new_sum = cur_sum + num
        if new_sum not in ANSWER:
            new_elements = elements.copy()
            new_elements.append(num)
            QUEUE.append((new_sum, new_elements))

for key, item in ANSWER.items():
    print("{0}: {1}".format(key, item))
```

Every time you are appending to the `QUEUE`, you are effectively adding leaf nodes. If you *just* perform BFS without storing the results (i.e. dynamic programming), then you will hit exponential time. The way the above code copies and carries around the list of `elements` is highly inefficient. You could instead store `ANSWER[28] = ANSWER[29] - 1`, for example, such that when you actually want to retrieve the full list of elements for a given sum, you can recursively follow the `ANSWER` to retrieve it.

Note that the above program will never terminate if the `DESIRED_SUM` can't be derived from the given list of elements.